# In what direction should I orient the dipole antenna on my 2.4 GHz RC transmitter?

Tags: antenna, transmitter, signal-strength

My RC transmitter has a movable antenna that allows me to change its orientation, like this one:

[image]

In what direction should I point my 2.4 GHz RC transmitter antenna for best range and signal penetration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The antenna should be aligned to match the orientation of the antenna on your aircraft; generally this will be vertical, but for more acrobatic aircraft a compromise of 45° might be appropriate for greater reliability but lower performance. For more detail see [this question](https://drones.stackexchange.com/q/65).

Some manufacturers of off-the-shelf equipment will recommend an orientation in their user manuals - in this case, follow the instructions they give.